# Tab scene doesn't work, when I run main class there is Tab Pane cast error

Tags: javafx, tabs, scenebuilder

I have created a scene on scene builder using TabPane but when I run I have this error:

```
gen 20, 2024 9:02:31 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
AVVERTENZA: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @46f15f7f'
gen 20, 2024 9:02:32 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
AVVERTENZA: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 19 by JavaFX runtime of version 18.0.2
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class javafx.scene.control.TabPane cannot be cast to class javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane (javafx.scene.control.TabPane and javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at it.polito.s284166.Tesi.EntryPoint.start(EntryPoint.java:19)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
```

this is the film fxml of scene builder:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<TabPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="540.0" prefWidth="768.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="it.polito.s284166.Tesi.FXMLController">
  <tabs>
    <Tab text="Ricerca">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightyellow;">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="513.0" fitWidth="768.0" opacity="0.56" pickOnBounds="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../../sfondo-di-impronta-di-tracce-di-pneumatici-gialli/SL-092920-35860-24.jpg" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <TextField fx:id="txtKilometer" layoutX="413.0" layoutY="22.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="254.0" promptText="Inserisci un valore numerico" style="-fx-border-color: black;" />
                  <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="22.0" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="178.0" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black;" text="Max Chilometri">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="16.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="115.0" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="178.0" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black;" text="Tipo di carburante">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="16.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <ComboBox fx:id="cmbColor" layoutX="413.0" layoutY="159.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="254.0" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: Black;" />
                  <RadioButton layoutX="413.0" layoutY="210.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Prima Mano">
                     <toggleGroup>
                        <ToggleGroup fx:id="owner" />
                     </toggleGroup></RadioButton>
                  <RadioButton layoutX="566.0" layoutY="210.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Seconda mano" toggleGroup="$owner" />
                  <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="68.0" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="178.0" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black;" text="Prezzo Massimo">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="16.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="txtPrice" layoutX="413.0" layoutY="68.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="254.0" promptText="Inserisci un valore numerico" style="-fx-border-color: black;" />
                  <ComboBox fx:id="cmbFuel" layoutX="413.0" layoutY="115.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="254.0" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: Black;" />
                  <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="159.0" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="178.0" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black;" text="Colore">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="16.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Button fx:id="btnCreaGrafo" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="244.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doCreaGrafo" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="694.0" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black;" text="Cerca veicolo" />
                  <TableView fx:id="table" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="286.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="697.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn fx:id="ID" prefWidth="48.000030517578125" text="ID" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="Make" prefWidth="72.80001831054688" text="Marca" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="Model" prefWidth="172.00006103515625" text="Modello" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="engine" prefWidth="70.4000244140625" text="Cavalli" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="year" prefWidth="75.0" text="Anno" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="kilometer" prefWidth="135.99993896484375" text="Chilometri" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="price" prefWidth="119.199951171875" text="Prezzo" />
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </children></AnchorPane>
      </content>
    </Tab>
      <Tab text="Ricerca Avanzata">
         <content>
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="514.0" fitWidth="768.0" opacity="0.56" pickOnBounds="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../../sfondo-di-impronta-di-tracce-di-pneumatici-gialli/SL-092920-35860-24.jpg" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <ComboBox fx:id="cmbAuto1" layoutX="403.0" layoutY="32.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="326.0" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: Black;" />
                  <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="32.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="304.0" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black;" text="Seleziona auto">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="16.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="74.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="304.0" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black;" text="Inserisci budget">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="16.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="txtBudget1" layoutX="403.0" layoutY="74.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="327.0" promptText="Inserisci un valore numerico" style="-fx-border-color: black;" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnRicorsione1" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="127.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doRicorsione" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="694.0" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black;" text="Trova combinazione migliore">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="16.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <TextArea fx:id="txtResult1" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="191.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="700.0" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black;" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </content>
      </Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

this is the FXMLController class:

```
package it.polito.s284166.Tesi;

import it.polito.s284166.Tesi.model.*;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;


public class FXMLController {
    
    private Model model;
    
    @FXML
    private TabPane mainPane;

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> ID;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> Make;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> Model;

    @FXML
    private Button btnCreaGrafo;

    @FXML
    private Button btnRicorsione1;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<?> cmbAuto1;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<?> cmbColor;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<?> cmbFuel;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> engine;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> kilometer;

    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup owner;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> price;

    @FXML
    private TableView<?> table;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtBudget1;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtKilometer;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtPrice;

    @FXML
    private TextArea txtResult1;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> year;

    @FXML
    void doCreaGrafo(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void doRicorsione(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert ID != null : "fx:id=\"ID\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert Make != null : "fx:id=\"Make\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert Model != null : "fx:id=\"Model\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert btnCreaGrafo != null : "fx:id=\"btnCreaGrafo\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert btnRicorsione1 != null : "fx:id=\"btnRicorsione1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert cmbAuto1 != null : "fx:id=\"cmbAuto1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert cmbColor != null : "fx:id=\"cmbColor\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert cmbFuel != null : "fx:id=\"cmbFuel\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert engine != null : "fx:id=\"engine\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert kilometer != null : "fx:id=\"kilometer\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert owner != null : "fx:id=\"owner\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert price != null : "fx:id=\"price\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert table != null : "fx:id=\"table\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert txtBudget1 != null : "fx:id=\"txtBudget1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert txtKilometer != null : "fx:id=\"txtKilometer\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert txtPrice != null : "fx:id=\"txtPrice\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert txtResult1 != null : "fx:id=\"txtResult1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
        assert year != null : "fx:id=\"year\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";

    }
    
    public void setModel(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

}
```

this is the entryPoint class:

```
package it.polito.s284166.Tesi;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;

import it.polito.s284166.Tesi.model.Model;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class EntryPoint extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));
        BorderPane root = loader.load();
        FXMLController controller = loader.getController();
        Model model = new Model();
        controller.setModel(model);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/styles/Styles.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    

}
```

and this is the main class:

```
package it.polito.tdp.imdb;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntryPoint.main(args);
    }
}
```

I have created the scene of scene builder, I have copied and pasted the skeleton of the view on fxml controller class, I have runned the main class and appear that error, I have checked scene.fxml file but I don't find the BorderPane tag suggested from error message and I have not used that in fxml controller class too. Can you help to find the problem with this project?

Comment: The error is thrown on this line: `BorderPane root = loader.load();`. Given the root of your FXML file is a `TabPane`, you need to change it to: `TabPane root = loader.load();`.

Comment: Better yet, just use `Region` instead of `BorderPane`

Comment: Better, better yet `new Scene(loader.load())`.  Why create a variable that you're not going to use?